# Append text in richTextBox from more sources in C

Tags: c++, textbox

I want to add some more strings from different sources together but I doesn't seem to work...
My code

```
int num = 0;
string s = std::to_string(num);
this->richTextBox1->Text = "Copying files... (" + s + "%)"; //this doesn't work
```

P.S: How to add codes like - `num = num + 1`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work is because the `Text` property is not a `std::string`.

You can convert the resulting `std::string` to a `const char*` by using `c_str()`:

```
this->richTextBox1->Text = ("Copying files... (" + s + "%)").c_str();
```

Comment: Then what should I do? I'm totally noob ar C++

Comment: @user2023328 I've updated my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work, there are so many complicate errors when I compile it. I use a the "Windows Forms" from CLR tab

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the description which environment is involved, but since C++ is used, I assume that it is Managed C++ with WinForms and not C#.

Therefore, a working code of the given example would look like this:

```
// Environment is Managed C++ with .Net WinForms!
int num = 0;
std::string s = std::to_string(num);
String ^S = gcnew System::String(s.c_str()); // Convert std::string in System::String
this->richTextBox1->Text = "Copying files... (" + S + "%)"; //this code does compile now!
```

The variable **s** is once small for std::string and once large **S** for System::String.

While I don't quite understand what the question is about how to implement
**num = num+1;** , because this works the same way.

You can also write it as follows: **num+=num;**